# Line Length for Inline Python Documentation

Tags: python, coding-style, documentation, inline

When writing inline documentation, is there a standard method for line breaks when it comes longer lines of text (Obviously this shouldn't happen too frequently)?

For example:

```
"This modules does blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blah"
```

Or should it be:

```
"This modules does blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah 
blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah blah blah blah blahblah blah 
blah blah blah blah"
```

If there is no well defined standard or tradition for this I'm not really looking for a debate, in which case the question should probably just be closed. But if there is a standard or very common practice I would like to know what it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For mulitiline comments like the example in your question, you can also use """triple quotes""" for your comments to span over newlines.

[PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) style guide recommends to

> Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters

And also:

> For flowing long blocks of text (docstrings or comments), limiting the
>   length to 72 characters is recommended.

There is a particular section of the style guide concerning docstrings, a particular type of inline documentation, which you can find [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings).

Answer (score 0):

Lines are usually limited to 80 characters in the computer world, the PEP style guide recommends a maximum of 79.